# jQuery copy content and remove class from it before appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to clone the content of the div using jQuery, but from the copied content I want to find a class **active** and remove it before I use `appendTo` function.

So for example, I have this code:

```
<div class="box">
    <p>text</p>
    <div class="random active"></div>
</div>
```

I can copy the above code using this:

```
var content = $(this).find('.box').html();
```

Now how can I find the class **active** from the var `content` and remove it before I can `appendTo`?

Please note, I do not want to remove class from actual div from where I copied the content, I just want to remove from the copied code so that it is not included in the clone div.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try,

```
var content = $(this).find('.active').removeClass('active').closest('.box').html();
```

As per your new request,

```
var content = $(this).find('.box').clone().find('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: `.removeClass` will remove all appearances of `active` class or only first?

Comment: will remove all the active classes from descendants of the $(this) reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I said i want to remove only from the copied content not from the original div, this code will remove from the original div as well.

Comment: i think is useless to `find('.active')` and than `removeClass('active')` ... you can remove active class whithout find frist.

Comment: @Frogmouth who told like that..? cloned element is having a class `box`

Comment: sorry... you are right... i use `.children()` select inset element... your code is correct. my bad.

Comment: Thanks again, but sorry, if I alert(content.html()); it has only the content of elements which are inside the active class. I want to get content of All .box after removing the class.

Comment: to use: `alert(content.html())` you must change code like this:
`var content = $(this).find('.box').clone();
content.find('.active').removeClass('active')
console.log(content.html());`

Answer (score 2):

**My way to solve the problem:**

```
var content = $(this).find('.box').children().clone().removeClass("active");
```

`content` is a jQuery array with the content of `.box` (a clone of the content) with all element without `active` class.

**An alternative:**

If you need to remove the class only from an element you can add a step:

```
var content = $(this).find('.box').children().clone();
content.find(".random").removeClass("active");
```

**How can you use content variable:**

Right now you can `.appendTo()` `content` where you need:

```
content.appendTo("body"); //for example
```

**Debug code:**

To use: `alert(content.html())` try this:

```
var content = $(this).find('.box').clone();
content.children().removeClass("active");
alert(content.html()); //HTML string but it seems the best way to use DOM
```

but is better this way, using console:

```
var content = $(this).find('.box').children().clone().removeClass("active");
console.log(content);   // array of jQuery objects not simply HTML string
```

**An example:**

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Frogmouth/4dYM4/1/

enjoy, Frog.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$(content).find('.active').remove().appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
content = $(content).find('.active').removeClass('active')
```

---

Updated after OP's comment

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/B99mG/)

```
var content = $(this).find('.box').clone();
content = content.find('.active').removeClass('active').closest('.box');
alert(content.html());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking for something like this, but after this, if I alert(content); I cannot get the content, it says object object. How can I get the content in the variable?

Comment: @user966582 check updated answer with [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/B99mG/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
var content = $(this).find('.box').clone();
$(content).find('.active').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way, to remove and append element

```
        content = $('#content').clone();
        $('#content').remove();
        content.appendTo('#perntElement');
```